# Element not visible in firefox as well as chrome

Tags: java, eclipse, jquery-ui, selenium-webdriver

I am working in selenium webdriver 2.0, and I have to automate a script for running functional and cross-browser testing. I am getting an error of `element not visible` when I am trying to click on an element with the class `.divAdvSearchFeildListName&[data-id='30001']` for a drop down.

The same code works fine for some drop-downs to select a country name and jurisdiction from the same page on the same page. The error I am getting is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 47 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:22:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
Session ID: 2ca283f6-5703-4ef6-b07f-2dee99b531ab
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=22.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
    at com.anteambulo.SeleniumJQuery.Prog_Try_Six.automate(Prog_Try_Six.java:1112)
    at com.anteambulo.SeleniumJQuery.Prog_Try_Six.hCueIgn(Prog_Try_Six.java:122)
    at com.anteambulo.SeleniumJQuery.Prog_Try_Six.main(Prog_Try_Six.java:71)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:22:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/155366/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous8998336689581680973webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7682)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/155366/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous8998336689581680973webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10402)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/155366/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous8998336689581680973webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10421)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/155366/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous8998336689581680973webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10426)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/155366/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous8998336689581680973webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10366)
```

My code gets stuck at line number 6 in this code snippet. As you can see in the code I am trying to highlight that web element with a `5px` solid yellow border:

```
   jQuery EntitySearchTypeValue = browser.queryUntil(a1ValEntityDropDownList);
    setCellName(26,0,a1ValEntityDropDownListLabel,sheetReportGeneration);
    hCueExcel(1,1,26,sheetReportGeneration,browser,colNoForDiffBrowsers,EntitySearchTypeValue);
    System.out.println("Login Button found");
   // password.css("border", "none");
    EntitySearchTypeValue.css("border", "5px solid yellow");
    takescreenshot(a1ValFileNamePath,26,colNoForDifferentScreenShots,sheetSnapshotGeneration,workbook);
    ***EntitySearchTypeValue.get().click();***   
   //  browser.findElement(By.className("divAdvSearchFeildListName&[data-id='30001']")).click();
   // browser.getDrv().findElementByClassName("EntitySearchTypeValue&[data-id='30001']").click();
  //  browser.getDrv().findElementByCssSelector(".divAdvSearchFeildListName&[data-id='30001']").click();
   // document.querySelector(".field[data-test]");
   // browser.get()
   // By cssSelector = By.cssSelector(".field[data-test='testytest']");
    // or By.cssSelector(".field[data-test=testytest]")
    // or By.cssSelector(".field[data-test]")
    //bin.findElement(cssSelector).sendKeys("Hello");
    try{

     Thread.sleep(5000L);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```

The same code works fine in Firefox, but gets stuck at some point later in the code for other browsers. For Chrome it gets stuck in the beginning for the third drop-down in the same page. I have the `selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar` which is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that the element you are trying to click on is hidden. Make sure that the element is visible before click on it. You can add a wait if the element becomes visible after delay.

Apart from this you  should check the system configuration and it should be compatible.